# Checking a object property in LHS

Tags: clips

I need to check the existence of a value for an o'bject's property in a LHS.

```
(defrule check-property
    ?room <- (object (is-a ROOM))
    (integerp (send ?room get-property))   ; #1
    =>
    (printout ?*debug-print* "Room " ?room " has property"  crlf))
```

But it seems to me that #1 is not valuated in LHS. Instead if I put it in RHS, it returns TRUE.
Where am I wrong?

Thx,
Nic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the test conditional element to evaluate an expression in the LHS of a rule:

```
(defrule check-property
    ?room <- (object (is-a ROOM))
    (test (integerp (send ?room get-property)))
    =>
    (printout ?*debug-print* "Room " ?room " has property"  crlf))
```

It's better to explicitly retrieve the slot value by matching it rather than using the slot accessor as this will cause the condition to be reevaluated whenever the slot value changes:

```
(defrule check-property
    ?room <- (object (is-a ROOM)
                     (property ?property))
    (test (integerp ?property))
    =>
    (printout ?*debug-print* "Room " ?room " has property"  crlf))
```

Comment: What if `property` is a reference to another instance, and if I want to get a property of that instance? In other words, how do I get a certain property from an instance `a` which is associated with another instance `b`?

Comment: I created a new question regarding my above comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856745/clips-accessing-a-property-of-a-property