# CLIPS accessing a property of a property

Tags: clips, expert-system

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121490/checking-a-object-property-in-lhs) SO answer that it is

> better to explicitly retrieve the slot value by matching it rather
>   than using the slot accessor as this will cause the condition to be
>   reevaluated whenever the slot value changes

What if I want to access the property of a property? For example,

given two instances `a` and `b` of classes `A` and `B`, respectively.

`a` has a property called `ref_to_b` which is a reference to `b`.
`b` has a property called `some_prop_of_b`.

How do I match the following:

`a` with `ref_to_b` equal to `b` and `some_prop_of_b` equal to "some_string".

I tried this but got an error:

```
(defrule my_rule "comment me"
    (object (is-a A)
        (ref_to_b ?ref_to_b))
    (?ref_to_b
        (some_prop_of_b "some_string"))
=>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the instance name of the referenced instance in the ref_to_b slot and then use the name slot to match the reference:

```
CLIPS> 
(defclass A (is-a USER) (slot ref_to_b))
CLIPS> 
(defclass B (is-a USER) (slot some_prop_of_b))
CLIPS> 
(make-instance [b1] of B (some_prop_of_b "some_string"))
[b1]
CLIPS> 
(make-instance [b2] of B (some_prop_of_b "not_some_string"))
[b2]
CLIPS> 
(make-instance [a] of A (ref_to_b [b2]))
[a]
CLIPS> 
(defrule my_rule
   (object (is-a A) (ref_to_b ?name_b))
   (object (name ?name_b) (some_prop_of_b "some_string"))
   =>)
CLIPS> (agenda)
CLIPS> (send [a] put-ref_to_b [b1])
[b1]
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      my_rule: [a],[b1]
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Ah the name slot. That was the key.